# getElementsByClassName & IE8: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I know "`getElementsByClassName`" is not support by `IE8`. Do you know what can I use instead? I am getting annoying by error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

The HTML code is:

```
function sumar() {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('verdana14 toAdd');
var myLength = elems.length;
total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
   if (elems[i].value!="") {
       total += parseInt(elems[i].value,10);
       }
    }

var promedio = total/myLength;
parseFloat(document.getElementById('promediocal').value = promedio.toFixed(2));
}
```

This the input text that calls the javascript function:

```
<input name='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_2' type='text' class='verdana14 toAdd' id='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_2' style='width:50px' onChange='sumar()'/>
<input name='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_3' type='text' class='verdana14 toAdd' id='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_3' style='width:50px' onChange='sumar()'/>
<input name='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_4' type='text' class='verdana14 toAdd' id='AE_EA_1_BIV_003_4' style='width:50px' onChange='sumar()'/>
```

Comment: jQuery has a great CSS selector implementation (which includes class name searches): http://jquery.com/

Comment: I love jQuery too, and for something running IE8 it almost certainly wouldn't be prohibitive overhead, but for pure vanilla javascript querySelectorAll() is best answer, as long as namespaces are not in the picture.

Answer (score 63):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('.verdana14.toAdd')`.

See also my related [blog post](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2014/03/get-elements-by-class-name-ie8/).

Comment: This would offer the simplest solution, but you should have `querySelectorAll` to get multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my typo by replacing qs with qsA.

Comment: I downloaded the jQuery and used document.querySelectorAll('.verdana14.toAdd');

Comment: If you use native browser method (`document.querySelectorAll()`), you don't need jQuery to use it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 15):

`getElementsByClassName` method is not supported by IE8.

You should use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` (works in IE8+) or a library that implements that functionality - like:

- `jQuery`
- `Moo Tools`
- `DOJO`
- `YUI`
- `Prototype`

  ... Among others...

---

`querySelectorAll` support:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

`getElementsByClassName` support:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11

Answer (score 9):

You could write your own. Something like:

```
function GEBCN(cn){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName) // Returns NodeList here
        return document.getElementsByClassName(cn);

    cn = cn.replace(/ *$/, '');

    if(document.querySelectorAll) // Returns NodeList here
        return document.querySelectorAll((' ' + cn).replace(/ +/g, '.'));

    cn = cn.replace(/^ */, '');

    var classes = cn.split(/ +/), clength = classes.length;
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), elength = els.length;
    var results = [];
    var i, j, match;

    for(i = 0; i < elength; i++){
        match = true;
        for(j = clength; j--;)
            if(!RegExp(' ' + classes[j] + ' ').test(' ' + els[i].className + ' '))
                match = false;
        if(match)
            results.push(els[i]);
    }

    // Returns Array here
    return results;
}
```

Will work pretty well, but you could write a faster one if you want to. Then you can just change:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('verdana14 toAdd');
```

To:

```
GEBCN('verdana14 toAdd');
```

Comment: You need to change `cn.replace(' ', '.')` because it will only replace the first space. You'll need a `g`lobal regex that will also consider adjacent spaces to be one. Same with your `cn.split(/ /)`, it should be global, and test for adjacent spaces, and it should include other space characters, like tabs, so `\s` is probably better.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks yeah I got confused by PHP and forgot which one replaces all without the g modifier. I purposefully switched from `\s` to ` ` because I don't think the function will be called with tabs or newlines. I modified it to trim off trailing spaces as well.

Comment: Yeah, probably a safe bet about the tabs/new lines.

Comment: @amnotiam Also there is no need for a `g` flag on cn.split. It wouldn't do anything because split finds all matches anyways.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the split.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery, or filter the results from getElementsByTag

Answer (score -3):

you may try using jquery as it have alternative class selector to get the elements by there class names.
$(".testclass").each... it will give you required elements by class names