# Pulling class elements into an array and then summing them up

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to Javascript and I need some help to do this. The classes will be pulling from different tables (like below). I just need a way to pull all the cell values out of each class and sum them up. So classone = 1234 + 1234. I'm confused as to whether document.getElementByClassName works? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr><td class="classone">1234</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="classtwo">1234</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="classthree">1234</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table>
<tbody>
   <tr><td class="classone">1234</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="classtwo">1234</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="classthree">1234</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using bare javascript, or with the help of something like jquery?

Comment: Either. I just need it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` works except in IE (8 and below).

```
function sumByClass(classname){
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    var i, sum = 0;

    for(i = els.length; i--;)
        sum += parseInt(els[i].innerText || els.textContent, 10)

    return sum;
}
```

For IE8 support you can use querySelectorAll:

```
function sumByClass(classname){
    var els;
    var i, sum = 0;

    if(document.getElementsByClassName) // Modern
        els = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    else if(document.querySelectorAll) // IE 8
        els = document.querySelectorAll((' ' + classname).replace(/ +/g, '.'));

    for(i = els.length; i--;)
        sum += parseInt(els[i].innerText || els.textContent, 10)

    return sum;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FSPRx/)

[**JSFiddle** (With IE8 support)](http://jsfiddle.net/FSPRx/1/)

For IE 7 and 6 you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method/9569020#9569020) to define a function which gets elements by class name, returning a NodeList in IE8+, but an array in IE 7 and below. For a cross-browser solution you can just use that list/array to sum the values the same way I do above:

```
function sumByClass(classname){
    var els = GEBCN(classname);
    var i, sum = 0;

    for(i = els.length; i--;)
        sum += parseInt(els[i].innerText || els.textContent, 10)

    return sum;
}
```

Of course you could always use a framework/library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) make this much simpler as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JavaScript, I would take a look at jQuery JavaScript Library. You have to add it to your all of your html pages using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

This solution uses it and works in all modern browsers as well as far back as IE 6.

```
function addByClass(classname) {
    var sum = 0;
    $.each($(' ' + classname).replace(/ +/g, '.'), function(i, item) {
        sum += parseInt($(item).html());
    });
    return sum;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/BwmZb/2/

Comment: That doesn't work if class name has multiple classes like `addByClass('classone classtwo') != 4936`. Otherwise it works fine, but if needed for multiple classes the way `getElementsByClassName` works you can just change `"." + classname` to `(' ' + classname).replace(/ +/g, '.')` to make it so `addByClass('classone classtwo') == 4936`

Comment: So does the script line go in the head of the page?

Comment: yes, and make sure it goes about any other JavaScript line so that you can use it in other external JavaScript files you link to.