# Javascript does not work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a javascript to ask the user to confirm that they want to leave my website. This is how it looks:

```
  function confirmLeave()
  {
    if(confirm("Do you want to leave my webpage?")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if(window.event) {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

function initiate ()
{
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("external-link");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = confirmLeave;
    }   

}
window.onload = initiate;
```

It works good in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8. I know that `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work and I tried to remake my code using `document.getElementsbyTakeName` but haven't got it to work. This is what I came up with:

```
function confirmLeave()
      {
        if(confirm("Do you want to leave my webpage?")) {
          return true;
        } else {
          if(window.event) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
          } else {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          return false;
        }
      }

funciton initiate ()
{
    if(document.getElementsByClassName)
    {   
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("external-link");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = confirmLeave;
    } 
    } else {
     var links = document.getElementsByTagName("external-link");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = confirmLeave;
    }
    }
}
window.onload = initiate;
```

The `external-link` is the class I'm using for the links that are to leave my webpage.

Comment: `funciton = initiate;` this line seems incorrect. Could be like: `var initiate = function() ...`

Comment: Ah, just a typo. Fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `document.querySelectorAll(".external-link")`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)

Comment: Just replacing document.getElementsByClass?

Comment: Yes. Although it takes a CSS selector as input, so `getElementsByClassName("external-link")` becomes `querySelectorAll(".external-link")`.

Comment: @Benji, Yes. According to MSDN `W3C Selectors API provides two methods for using selectors to select objects: querySelector, which selects the first object that matches your criteria; and querySelectorAll, which returns all objects that match your criteria. You can select among the document objects or those that descend from a common container object.`

Answer (score 0):

consider including jQuery library if that's a viable option for you.
then you may write something like this:

```
$('.external-link').click(function() { confirmLeave() });
```

Comment: I'd like to not use any library

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `document.getElementsByTagName()` takes an element as it's input, e.g. `div`, `span` or `a`. `external-link` is not an element, so it'll never return anything.

For IE8, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".external-link")`. It takes a CSS selector as it's input.

If you need to support older browsers too, you could try using https://gist.github.com/2397759 which is a polyfill to make `getElementsByClassName` work on browsers that don't support it natively.