# How to hide other tabs's content and display only the selected tab's content

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, tabs

When I click on a particular tab the other tabs's content should be hidden but it is not hiding. This is all the code I have.

```js
function showStuff(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display === "block") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff('tabs-1')">City</li>
  <li id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff('tabs-2')">Country</li>
  <li id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff('tabs-3')">Humanity</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" style="display : none">
  <p>Proin elit m</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2" style="display : none">
  <p>M massa ut d</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3" style="display : none">
  <p> sodales.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Could you add the HTML for the tab content please?

Comment: Did you set `id` for your tab contents?

Comment: yeah all my tab contens have Id's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Giving all the *tab content* elements a common CSS class makes selecting and styling them much easier, for example in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm8Dm/) and code below.

**CSS**

```
.tabContent {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // change tabsX into tabs-X in order to find the correct tab content
    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side bar tabs">
    <li id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff(this)">City</li>
    <li id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff(this)">Country</li>
    <li id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff(this)">Humanity</li>  
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent">
    <p>Proin elit m</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent">
    <p>M massa ut d</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="tabContent">
    <p> sodales.</p>
</div>
```

I have also updated the `showElement` function to be more generic so that there is less code duplication when hiding and showing the correct tab content.

The only caveat is that [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) is not available in IE8 or below. [Other (modern) browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName) have this function but there are alternatives - see [getElementsByClassName & IE8: Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method).

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set a `display: none` for all of your tab contents.

e. g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTab(selected, total)
{
  for(i = 1; i <= total; i += 1)
  {
    document.getElementById('tabs-' + i).style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.getElementById('tabs-' + selected).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<div id="tabs-1" style="display: none">tab1</div>
<div id="tabs-2" style="display: none">tab2</div>
<div id="tabs-3" style="display: none">tab3</div>

<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li id = "tabs1" onclick = "showTab(1,3)">City</li>
  <li id = "tabs2" onclick = "showTab(2,3)">Country</li>
  <li id = "tabs3" onclick = "showTab(3,3)">Humanity</li>  
</ul>
```

If there is something like this with your code, I'm sure that it's going to work. BTW, Check your Console window for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Those are the Tab headings, for the tab content I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do it:

```
<ul class="side bar tabs">
    <li  id = "tabs1" onclick = "showStuff('tabs-1')">City</li>
    <li  id = "tabs2" onclick = "showStuff('tabs-2')">Country</li>
    <li  id = "tabs3" onclick = "showStuff('tabs-3')">Humanity</li>  
</ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function showStuff (id) 
  {

        document.getElementById("tabs-1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tabs-2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tabs-3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";

  }
  </script>

  <div id="tabs-1" style="display:none">tabs 1 content</div>
  <div id="tabs-2" style="display:none">tabs 2 content</div>
  <div id="tabs-3" style="display:none">tabs 3 content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">City</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Country</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Humanity</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">..............</div>
 <div id="tabs-2">..............</div>
 <div id="tabs-3">..............</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, using jQuery and jQueryUI is not necessarily the best option. It has the overhead of a lot of JavaScript code.

Comment: @andyb : agree, removed that line. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 function showStuff(id){
$('#tabs1').empty();
  $('#tab2').show();
}
```

or the other way

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for a jQuery solution.