# jquery IE8/9/10 Bind to click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Facing an issue with IE and jquery. The code is working in all other browsers but breaks when used in IE. Fairly simple implementation. But I am javascript novice.

```
console.log('hi ie');

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery(".controlApply").on("click", function (event) {
            pollVisibility();
            console.log('after poll');
        });
    }, 1000);
});
//This method checks is a specific div is shown. Dirty way to check if a report is being processed
function pollVisibility() {
    console.log('poll');
    if (microstrategy.bones.rwb_viewer.objectID == '7647F4F611E2B39B923E0080EF058C78') {
        if (!jQuery('#divWaitBox').attr('style')) {
            console.log('divWaitBox');
            //wait did not appear
            microstrategy.getViewerBone().commands.exec('refresh');
        } else if (jQuery('#divWaitBox').attr('style').indexOf('hidden') != -1) {
            console.log('hidden');
            microstrategy.getViewerBone().commands.exec('refresh');
        } else {
            console.log('other');
            setTimeout(pollVisibility, 800);
        }
    } else {}
}
```

The console.log never is called however the document.ready seems to work in IE

The doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
```

If its wrong, I cannot change it. This is an extension of the MicroStrategy BI application.

Comment: Stupid question but, do you have the console open? otherwise the console.log won't work. Make sure you reload the page after you open the console.

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: You're not in quirks mode, are you? Don't forget your `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Yeah I was testing with console opened. It logs my 'console.log('ie sucks') at the top of js file just fine...

Comment: what version of jquery?

Comment: I just noticed this app is using /*! jQuery v1.10.2 ...... Good call, let me try latest.

Comment: @user3032973: That's about as close as you'll get to the latest without breaking IE8. If you upgrade to `jQuery 2.0.2`, IE8 won't work.

Comment: dumb question, but you DO have an element with the class="class" right?

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated.  Try with `.on()`.

Comment: Still doesnt work even with 2.0.3

Comment: This is too simple to be messing up with no error messages so maybe you don't have the basic setup correct? It should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X8wtT/

Comment: @RocketHazmat: `.bind()` isn't deprecated. It's just a recommendation to use `.on()`.

Comment: @user3032973: You can't use jQuery 2.x with IE 8 or lower.  If you want to support IE 8, you need to use 1.x.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Ah, yes.  You're right.

Comment: @user3032973: And how about that `doctype`?

Comment: Works for me in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/4r6T8/show (edit at http://jsfiddle.net/4r6T8)  P.S. What `poll();` do?

Comment: The doctype can be seen above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your jQuery version, your issue is likely the `.bind()` which should be performed with `.on()` like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="class" style="height:40px; width:40px; background-color:#ff0000;"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".class").on("click", function (event) {
        console.log('We clicked!');
        poll(); // <-- wtf does this do exactly??
    });
});
```

Comment: Nah, any version that supports `.on` will also support `.bind`. ;-) Using `.on` is preferred, but `.bind()` isn't deprecated.

Comment: @cookiemonster it hasn't been removed yet?

Comment: @cookiemonster I guess I should read the docs more often `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the` **preferred** `method`

Comment: Yeah, I've not heard of any plans to deprecate or remove it at this point. Still good advice to use `.on()`.

Comment: Hey OP, what does `poll();` do?

Comment: Hey sorry was at the gym. I am testing now with on. Will let you know.

Comment: poll() basically checks for a div so I will know if the application is done processing a report.

Comment: Adding a breakpoint and using /*! jQuery v1.10.2 the pollVisibility() is never hit.

Comment: Is it possible that the div is not rendered when page is ready? Can I put a delay on the .on() function?

Comment: .on() is preferred as it binds to the specified element even if it is created after the document is ready (eg generated elements). It was 'born' out of the .live() event if I remember correctly.

Comment: @c_kick `.on()` will not be able to bind itself to an element that is created on the page if you do not provide the correct specificity with a static parent -> dynamic child relationship.

Comment: @c_kick Check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y44NG/). Clicking Article 4 will do nothing unless you comment the first code block and uncomment the second.

Comment: You're doing it different (you're not applying .on() as I do); you should bind the .on event to the document, not the element you are targetting. See my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/5fUhe/

Comment: And here's the same example, showing that elements created after docready (press the 'dupe!' button) will work as well: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/K43Q3/

Comment: @c_kick Sorry about that, I did not realize you were binding it to the document. Your method does work and there is nothing wrong with it in terms of syntax nor compatibility but I just want to state that using the `document` as the parent is not the most efficient way because jQuery will potentially have to traverse so many children to find the `.article`. It is highly recommended to get as close to the child element as possible, preferably by giving the parent element an ID.

Comment: Agreed! I'd love to see some benchmarks on this, in my experience it is very fast (even with a very large and complex DOM)

Comment: @c_kick It all comes down to what browsers you are trying to support and the single-threaded prowess of the CPU running that browser. You can check out [JSperf](http://jsperf.com/) because they run tests against a slew of browsers and browser versions. jQuery really shines when it comes to compatibility because if a browser doesn't support something natively then jQuery uses the next-best method. I am looking at IE8 and it's lack of [getElementsByClassName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)

Comment: Hey guys I appreciate the help. All of your solutions seem to be correct. Its hard to tell what the problem is because this is an extension of a very large application and there is a ton of JS/ajax being executed when the page is rendered. Cant get .on to work for some reason. Works perfectly in chrome/ff:(

Comment: IF I call 'jQuery(".controlApply").on("click", function (event) {
  pollVisibility(); 
  });' After the page is renderd in the console everything works great....

Comment: The content may be added using ajax, would the solution change if this was the case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this javascript is that it was attempting to alter a page which is being built with some ajax framework. Its the MicroStrategy BI application. if I put a break point after document ready there is no content renderd on the page.

The solutions on this page helped me get here which should cover if/ff/chrome

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
      jQuery(".controlApply").on("click", function (event) {
          pollVisibility();
      });
});



function test(){
       jQuery('.mstrTransform').on('click', '.controlApply', function(){
           pollVisibility();
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have been having a night mare with this exact same issue in IE 11. I was trying to jQuery append() information to a div element. While running the console, the action intermittently worked. If console was closed, nothing happened, it was as if the script was completely ignored. This included an alert statement.

By commenting out the console.log statements IE 11 behaved as expected (which still feels incorrect). I ran the same script in MS Edge and Chrome with the console.logs and everything ran as expected. What I have learned is that console.log is the culprit. This is a common thing between our codes and I am working on IE 11 and the issue still persists. :(