# How to get the description/text below the first url to appear on google search results?

Tags: excel, vba

How does one get the description of the first link to appear on google search results?

**TEST CODE  UPDATE 1/24/2017**

Been getting the ' object doesnt support method/property' message

```
Dim URl As String, lastRow As Long
Dim xmlHttp As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object



lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

    URl = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", URl, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)
    Set objResultDiv = html.GetElementsByClassName("f slp")(0)

    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    Cells(i, 4) = objResultDiv.innerText
```

Comment: Can you please explain, what do you mean by "the text below the link"? If you search for [Stack overflow on google](https://www.google.sk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=fe-EWLGgFLGE8QewjrLQAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=stack+overflow), what is the text you are after? The "Stack Overflow" or the "Stack Overflow is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge, and advance their careers."

Comment: Please provide at least one or two concrete examples of search phrase and desired outputs.

Comment: If i search "Accounting for Investments, Equities, Futures and Options"
I am looking to fetch the "R. Venkata Subramani - 2011 - ‎Business & Economics" which is under the green url

Answer (score 1):

### <s>Span class="st"</s>

I believe you are looking for `<span class="st">` inside the `<div class="rc">`

### Edit #1

If we search for [Accounting for Investments, Equities, Futures and Options](https://www.google.sk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ei-GWLCEOYOO8QfghJSQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=Accounting+for+Investments%2C+Equities%2C+Futures+and+Options), and we want the text *R. Venkata Subramani - 2011 - ‎Business & Economics*, below the green url, like in the picture:

[image]

Then what we need is indeed the `<div class="f slp">`, as you OP pointed out.
[image]

So to get the text from it we can use code:

```
set objResultDiv = html.GetElementsByClassName("f slp")(0) 'note the plural, element*s*
cells(i, 4) = objResultDiv.innerText
```

### Object doesn't support this property or method response

HTMLDocument has one additional method to get a collection of elements.

```
set objResultDiv = .querySelectorAll(".f.slp")
cells(i, 4) = objResultDiv(index).innerText` 'replace index with number
```

Comment: i am vaguely familiar with vba..is it coded this way? (refer to updated post) @branislav-kollár

Comment: actually looking for the text inside <div class="f slp'> @branislav kollár

Comment: @AbbieLatonio See Edit #1 in my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you sir, i have tried including the code but 'object doesnt support this property or method' would always flash.

am i missing anything?

Comment: @AbbieLatonio, I have updated my answer. Based on tips given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Comment: i tried including the code but it flashes 'invalid reference' while highlighitng .queryselectorAll, so i tried to include 'html' before .queryselectorAll, and 'document' in another instance... (html.queryselectorall & document.queryselectorall) having both to fail as well with 'object doesnt support this method' msg

Comment: @AbbieLatonio, you are right. The html object was missing from my code, I had it inside the `With` block. For the problem at hand, I ran out of ideas.